# What is the best definitive way in apex to determine if an organization has enabled Custom Fiscal Years

Tags: apex, custom-fiscal-year

Once Custom Fiscal Years have been enabled, it's an irreversible decision. I had thought that the existence of any records in the FiscalYearSettings table indicated that Custom Fiscal Years had been enabled but I am now looking at an instance that clearly has Standard Fiscal Year enabled but also has records in the FiscalYearSettings table. Ideas?

Comment: I would have used the *FiscalYearSettings* object and assume that, if it had any records, that *Custom Fiscal Years* (CFY) was enabled.
I just tested with a brand new Developer org and that checks out true. Before enabling CFY, FiscalYearSettings has no records. After enabling CFY (and defining my first set of periods!) FiscalYearSettings has records.

The org that you're looking at, do you have any history on it? Could it be a very old org? Could it have been possible to disable CFY in the past (it's not possible now) and that it had been enabled in the past?

Comment: The above is not true.   Enabling forecasting over standard fiscal years will also create records in the FiscalYearSettigns table as well as the Period table.   This is not the best definitive way, as it will definitely be wrong sometimes.   Checking this table for records where (YearType != 'Standard') may be more accurate, but at this point, I would not call it "definitive" although it seems to work... so far.     Would definitely appreciate authoritative documentation on this, but haven't found any.

Answer (score 1):

10 years late... looks like this problem still exists, this is what I am working on, taking advantage of the fact that FISCAL SOQL calculations will throw QueryExceptions if it is enabled.

```
 private static Boolean isCustomFiscalEnabled(){

    // "Fiscal date calculations are not allowed when the custom fiscal year preference is enabled"

    try {
        Database.query('SELECT FISCAL_YEAR(closedate) FROM OPPORTUNITY GROUP BY FISCAL_YEAR(closedate) LIMIT 1');
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Should be QueryException, but if not, I'd rather have it fail-safe so that I just use the less error_prone CALENDAR_YEAR
        return true;
    }
        
}
```